# Повторение движения мышкой С#, Unity 2D

Tags: c#, unity3d, интерфейс, ui

Я написал программу, которая при нажатии ЛКМ, оставляет за курсором след из обьектов. При каком коде программа должна понимать, что следуюший "рисунок" похож/непохож на прошлый? Код и скрин проекта приложен к вопросу

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
public class Blade : MonoBehaviour

{
    bool IsChase = false;
    Rigidbody2D rb;
    Camera cam;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject Targ;
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        cam = Camera.main;
    }
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
            StartChase();
        else if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
            StopChase();
        Chase();
    }
    void StartChase()
    {
        IsChase = true;
    }

    void StopChase()
    {
        IsChase = false;
    }
    void Chase()
    {
        if (IsChase)
        {
            rb.position = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
            Instantiate(Targ, (rb.position), Quaternion.identity);
        }
            

    }
}
```

Ps: Сам понимаю вопрос далеко не легкий и здесь на него наверняка вообще не дадут ответов, но
тем не менее только на этом сайте мне могут дать ответ
[[image: Blade это курсор, Target это синий след][1]]

Comment: А что если установить интервал между созданием обьектов, сохранить все обьекты в массив и сравнивать разницу координат каждого обьекта?

Comment: Интересная идея, хоть у меня и нет должного опыта, я все равно попробую

Comment: Скорее всего по координатам не получится, так как количество точек может быть разное. Я думаю можно аппроксимировать исходное и конечное множество точек.  Отметить на аппроксимированных прямых фиксированное количество опорных точек,  и сравнивать вектора направлений из каждых точек попарно.